# Use linq distinct function?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I use linq distinct operator here to remove remove duplicate courses.Cours.Name,

```
var coursesList = from courses in not_subsribe
  select new SelectListItem
  {
      Text = courses.Cours.Name,
      Value = courses.Cours.ID
      .ToString()
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy` on an anonymous type with both properties to make them distinct:

```
var coursesList = 
     from c in not_subsribe
     group c by new { Id = c.Cours.ID, Name = c.Cours.Name } into g
     order by g.Key.Name
     select new SelectListItem
     {
         Text = g.Key.Name,
         Value = g.Key.Id
     };
```

That works because an anonymous type automatically overrides `Equals`+`GetHashCode` for you what is needed for `GroupBy` or `Distinct`. So now you could also use `Distinct`:

```
var coursesList = not_subsribe
.Select(c => new { Id = c.Cours.ID, Name = c.Cours.Name })
.Distinct()
.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
.Select(x => new SelectListItem
     {
         Text = g.Key.Name,
         Value = g.Key.Id
     });
```

Comment: Or you could just `Select` the anonymous object and then call `Distinct`.

Comment: @Rawling: good point, i've edited my answer. I've used `GroupBy` since  OP used already query syntax and i don't like mixing query and method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var coursesList = courses.DistinctBy(c => courses.Cours.Name)
                         .Select(crs => new SelectListItem
                                          {
                                              Text = crs.Cours.Name,
                                              Value = crs.Cours.ID.ToString()
                                          });
```

Sorry, I forgot to mention that `DistinctBy` method is available in a 3rd party library called **MoreLINQ**. This library is available for download using Nuget Package manager from here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/

And you can find out more about MoreLINQ from here: https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

Comment: You should at least have mentioned that `DistinctBy` is not part of .NET but of MoreLINQ.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry, I forgot to mention about MoreLINQ. Thanks for reminding me.